# Array of arrays with headers to array of hashes(and then JSON)

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, csv, ruby-hash

How can I convert array of arrays (CSV-liks with headers) to an array of hashes ?

```
headers = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz']]
data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]...]
arr_of_arrs = headers + data

arr_of_arrs_to_structured_hash
```

expected output be like

```
[
 {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
 {foo: 4, bar: 5, baz: 6}
 {foo: 7, bar: 8, baz: 9}
]
```

EDIT : sorry I just realized my output wasn't clear.
Basically the data ara array of rows just like in CSV (except my data isn't coming from a CSV)

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Show us your code attempt. Currently it looks like you kind-of started then bailed and want us to write it for you, which is off-topic as SO isn't a code writing service. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" is important. A hint toward solving the problem is that `map`, `zip` and `to_h` are your friends.

Comment: The logic is not clear. How is the input related to the expected output?

Comment: Did you start with an actual CSV file? Then you probably want to consider using the CSV gem, it will save you the hassle of creating your arrays of arrays.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry about that just realized indeed my example wasn't clear (and there was a typo on the last value). I have actually looked at a lot of CSV-related posts and blog enties, but they all mention how to go read/parse CSV but not really how to convert such an array of arrays to hash/JSON (or I'd have to write to a CSV file first =_=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headers = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz']]
data = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]

data.map(&headers.first.method(:zip)).map(&:to_h)
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#    "foo" => 1
#    "bar" => 2,
#    "baz" => 3,
#  },
#  [1] {
#    "foo" => 2
#    "bar" => 3,
#    "baz" => 4,
#  }
# ]
```